# Each time when a 'users' logs on to Windows 7 they're prompted to setup their Outlook 2007 profile

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook-2007, login, user-profiles

We're currently trialling Windows 7 to replace XP.  One problem I have is that each time a 'user' logs in, they're prompted to setup their Outlook 2007 profile.

Has anyone seen this?

Answer (score 1):

Do you use Roaming Profiles? Do your individual user's accounts have permissions to create new roaming profile folders themselves on the network?

Windows 7 uses version 2 roaming profiles, XP uses version 1, they're not compatible. Windows 7 will try to create a *username.V2* roaming profile on the same network share as the user's old roaming profile. If this fails, the user won't be notified but Windows will be unable to save the user's profile, meaning that next time they log in it will treat them as a totally new user and will go through the same setup and failure to save again.